# Here Maps - iOS Premium- infoBubble

Tags: ios, here-api

I am trying to display a popup above the marker when the marker is selected. But infoBubble functionality is not implemented in premium SDK.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use MapOverlays instead: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapOverlay.html

Then add you implementation to the MapView via: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapView(im)addMapOverlay:

The idea behind is, that you can use a normal UIView (very flexible, your own design, etc.) and stick it to a position on the map (and the mapview will keep it in place then).

Comment: Same applies to Android, corresponding Stackoverflow answer for Android is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409090/android-here-map-premium-plan-map-infobubbleadapter-hideinfobubble-getinfobu