# Here Map Premium plan Map.InfoBubbleAdapter() ,hideInfoBubble ,getInfoBubbleContents and isInfoBubbleVisible missing?

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to show the custom layout when user clicks on the marker object. 
The basic pack code works properly .

However when i shifted to premium pack it does not have 
Map.InfoBubbleAdapter(),hideInfoBubble,getInfoBubbleContents and isInfoBubbleVisible.

I am not even able to open the infoBubble when user click on marker too.

This is the code for custom view in basic pack i used.

```
  hereMap.get(new Map.InfoBubbleAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public View getInfoBubbleContents(MapMarker mapMarker2) {
                                   return null;
                                }

                               @Override
                                public View getInfoBubble(MapMarker mapMarker2) {
                                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_marker_infowindow, null);
                                    TextView infoWindowText = view.findViewById(R.id.infoMessage);
                                    infoWindowText.setText(mapMarker2.getTitle());
                                   return view;
                                }
                           });
```

and this is the code that i was using on click of marker

```
  @Override
        public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> objects) {

            for (ViewObject object : objects) {
                if (object.getBaseType() == ViewObject.Type.USER_OBJECT && ((MapObject) object).getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {
                    MapMarker mapMarker = (MapMarker) object;
                    System.out.println("Title is................." + mapMarker.getTitle());

                    if (!mapMarker.isInfoBubbleVisible()) {
                        mapMarker.getInfoBubbleContents();
                    } else {
                        mapMarker.hideInfoBubble();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

How can i show the custom info bubble when user click on the marker?

Answer (score 0):

You should use sticky map overlays instead:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapOverlay.html

Then add your MapOverlay implementation to the Map via Map.addMapOverlay:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#addMapOverlay-com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapOverlay-

The idea behind is, that you can use a normal Views (very flexible, your own design, etc.) and stick it to a position on the map (and the map will keep it in place then). This gives you full flexibility on logic and design.

Comment: Same applies for iOS, and the corresponding iOS answer to this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219434/here-maps-ios-premium-infobubble

Comment: how to create a onClick event on mapOverlay? For example i have 10 markers and i want to show one infoWindow at a time . I tried to add custom view in MapOverlay but its not taking it . Can you please give a example  to follow .

Comment: i tried this but the marker disappear after taping on map .
        mMapMarker = new MapMarker(geoCoordinate, marker_img);
        mMapMarker.setTitle(dataDisplay);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_marker_infowindow, null);
        TextView infoWindowText = view.findViewById(R.id.infoMessage);
        infoWindowText.setText(mMapMarker.getTitle());
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(view, geoCoordinate);
        mapObjects.add(mMapMarker);
        hereMap.addMapObject(mMapMarker);
        hereMap.addMapOverlay(mapOverlay);

Comment: The Marker also gets disapeard when zoom and only infoWindow is seen. How to fix this issue??