# Here Map Premium plan issue in setting MapOverlay custom view on top of marker

Tags: android, here-api

I want to add a **custom layout Infowindow** on **top** of the **marker**. Android Here map **Basic pack** was having the following features **Map.InfoBubbleAdapter() ,hideInfoBubble ,getInfoBubbleContents and isInfoBubbleVisible** which are now **missing** in the **Premium** **pack** .

As **suggested** in [Here Map Premium plan Map.InfoBubbleAdapter() ,hideInfoBubble ,getInfoBubbleContents and isInfoBubbleVisible missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409090/here-map-premium-plan-map-infobubbleadapter-hideinfobubble-getinfobubblecont)

This are the list of issues.

1. I have implemented **MapOverlay** which seems to give custom layout 
   but its **not aligned** to the **marker**.
2. The **infoWindow** is getting **visible** when i am trying to **zoom in**,even when i have **not** **tuned** on the **visibility** of layout.
3. The **position** of **infoWindow** is **not** on the **geoCordinate** that were set to mapOverlay.

I have **20 different marker** and i want to show the custom info window when user taps on any marker and turn off the previous marker .
I tried the code below but its not working and there seems **no documentation on implementation**.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> objects) {

            for (ViewObject object : objects) {
                if (object.getBaseType() == ViewObject.Type.USER_OBJECT && ((MapObject) object).getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {
                    MapMarker mapMarker = (MapMarker) object;
                    if(!isMapMarkerViewVisible()){
                        setInfoWindow(mapMarker);
                    }else{
                        removeInfoWindow();
                    }

                    return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
        for (MapObject mapObject : mapObjects) {
            if (mapObject.getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {
                removeInfoWindow();
            }
        }
        return super.onTapEvent(pointF);
    }


private void setInfoWindow(MapMarker mMark) {
    infoWindowText.setText(mMark.getTitle());
    infoWindowText.setTag(mMark.getTitle());
    mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(infoWindowView, mMark.getCoordinate());
    hereMap.addMapOverlay(mapOverlay);
}

private boolean isMapMarkerViewVisible(){
    return infoWindowView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
private void removeInfoWindow() {
    if(infoWindowView!=null) {
        if (infoWindowView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            infoWindowView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code behaves strangely .

When i try to **zoom in and out** the **info window strangely appears** on the map .Even when i have **not** set the **visibility**. 
The Above link have the code that was working but its not supporting now.

Comment: Did you solve this issue already? I saw also your question here: https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/180

Comment: Yes.But there are some glitches when  i  try to show different info window when panning the map.  And also the position of views  is different on different screen .The InfoBubble  was better . As its not having any problem in starter pack.  Please make it available in Premium pack.

Comment: Did you solve this issue already? I saw also your question here: github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/180

Answer (score 0):

Different from MapMarkers, the MapLabeledMarkers avoid overlapping with other user-defined labeled icons as well as built-in icons and texts on the map. It provides the possibility of using built-in POI icons by specifying a IconCategory or using an Image. One can specify multilingual texts to the icon. Depending on the current language and secondary language of Map, different language of text can be displayed.

```
MapLabeledMarker(GeoCoordinate loc)
```

Creates a MapLabeledMarker at a specific GeoCoordinate with a default POI icon.

```
MapLabeledMarker(GeoCoordinate loc, Image icon)
```

Creates a MapLabeledMarker at a specific GeoCoordinate with the specified Image.

For more detailed reference please refer & upgrade to newest version of SDK : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapLabeledMarker.html